# onSearchRequest is not getting called in child activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using tabGroup activity in my app for tabs. I am calling default search from one of my child activity. that child activity contains list view, and data in that list is coming from web service. But when I am not getting any result from webservice and my list is shown empty, onSearchRequest() does not get called. Search event directly goes to the parent activity and search does not get called..

Is there anyway to get the search event back on child activity.